# jQuery set focus

Tags: jquery, focus

How do I set focus in jQuery?  I've been trying to keep focus on a control when inside a focusout event but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(function() {
    $("#Line1").focusout(function() {
        alert("YOU CAN'T LEAVE HERE");
        $("#Line1").focus();
    });
});
```

My particular application is attempting to validate a field when it leaves focus and if it fails the validation I want the focus to remain on that control.

[Here is my code on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/palumbo/12j5jraa/3/)

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12j5jraa/5/)

In google chrome the above example is working

**HTML**

```
<table id="bz_eventtable" border="" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="bzHeading">Line 1:</td>
            <td class="bzDataTT">
                <input id="Line1" value="" maxlength="50" size="50" name="Line1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="errorLine1">
            <td colspan="2">
                <span>Error in Line 1</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bzHeading">Line 2:</td>
            <td class="bzDataTT">
                <input id="Line2" value="" maxlength="50" size="50" name="Line2"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#errorLine1").hide();
    $("#Line1").focusout(function() {
        $("#errorLine1").show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        $("#Line1").focus();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size : 8pt;
    padding-left:10px;
}
input[type="text"] {
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size : 8pt;
    width:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the focus in the `focusout` event, as the browser is already in progress of changing the focus. You can use a timer to change the focus back once the browser is done changing the focus:

```
$(function() {
  $("#Line1").focusout(function() {
    alert("YOU CAN'T LEAVE HERE");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $("#Line1").focus();
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/12j5jraa/6/

Note: You should really consider if there is any other way of doing whatever it is you want to accomplish. The behaviour of not allowing the user to leave a field can be **EXTREMELY ANNOYING!**